# Hide classes under search everywhere

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Most of the time, I don't care about searching for classes, and I do still want to see the recent files when I browse the other files in the project.

How do I just show recent files and files under search everywhere?

Something similar to how VSCode does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear *Classes* checkbox in filters popup:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a filter on my mac. It's only when I go to Files or Classes via shortcut that I can see their own filters. But they're only to filter out file extensions.

Comment: what webstorm version do you use?

Comment: it's not OS-specific; this new UI was added in 2018.3 - you can download the EAP from https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But before I install that, how are settings handled during upgrades? I customized a lot of things yesterday, and it'd be a shame to lose them.

Comment: you are normally prompted to import settings from previous version on the very first run